# Sum of distances from point on external bisector

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

> Given an angle $\angle{APB}$ and a point $P' \neq P$ on its external bisector, prove that $AP + BP < AP' + BP'$.

My first approach was to try Pythagoras, constructing points $A'$ and $B'$ orthogonal projections of $A$ and $B$ respectively onto the external bisector, and since $AA'$ and $BB'$ are perpendicular to the bisector, then triangles $AA'P'$ and $BB'P'$ are right triangles. But I got to a dead end because Pythagoras uses squares of sides and I need to prove a linear inequality.

My second idea was to notice that if we define an ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$ and a point $P$, and another ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$ and a point $P'$, then it is sufficient to prove that the semiaxis of the latter ellipse is greater than the former, since the equation of an ellipse is $AP + BP = k$. But I have not been able to continue from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be done with or without an ellipse.

$(1)$ Using ellipse

[image]

With $A, B$ as foci and $P$ a point on the ellipse, the external angle bisector is just the tangent at $P$.

Since the tangent lies outside the ellipse, it is easy to prove that $$AP+BP \lt AP'+BP'.$$

$(2)$ Without using ellipse.

[image]

Extend $AP$ to $B'$ such that $PB'=PB$ and join $P'B'$, $P'B$ as shown.

$\Delta PP'B \cong \Delta PP'B' \implies BP'=B'P'$.

Thus

\begin{align}
AP'+BP' &=AP'+B'P' \\
& \gt AB' \\
&= AP+PB' \\
&= AP+BP
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $A'$ be the reflection point of $A$ over the external bisector.

Then, since $A'$ is on the line $BP$, we have
$$AP' + BP'-(AP+BP)=A'P'+BP'-(A'P+BP)=A'P'+BP'-A'B\gt 0$$